# How to create new channel button for slack clone

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I need to create a button that creates a new Channel in my Slack Clone. I need the button to present a window, which the user can input the name of the channel they want, and after the user presses submit, the new channel is rendered in the channel list.

I can hard code the channels in the Room component. But I am lost on how to create new rooms dynamically. I am using React, Redux, React Hooks, and Socket.io

```
export default props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    join(props.match.params.roomname);
  }, props.match.params);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="channels">
        <Link to="/general">General</Link>
        <Link to="/foobar">Foobar</Link>
        <Link to="/CodeChat">Code Chat</Link>
        <button type="submit">New Rooom</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
      </div>
      <Messages room={props.match.params.roomname} />
      <ChatForm room={props.match.params.roomname} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I would like the New Room to create a link in the channel list.

Comment: where are you storing the underlying data for this chat system?  a server? what is the data shape? why not create a small form since you likely need data from the user when creating a channel?

Comment: I haven't set up the server yet. But I am using express on the backend

Comment: not sure we can help you without you helping us..IE, provide us with as much information as possible.  If you cannot do this, it probbably means you should take 15 minutes and draw out on paper what you want to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

You should store the links in state.

```
export default props => {
  const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([
    {name:"General",src:"/general"},
    {name:"Foobar",src:"/foobar"},
    {name:"Code Chat",src:"/CodeChat"}
  ])
  useEffect(() => {
    join(props.match.params.roomname);
  }, props.match.params);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="channels">
        rooms.map(room => <Link to={room.src}>{room.name}</Link>)
        <button type="submit">New Rooom</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
      </div>
      <Messages room={props.match.params.roomname} />
      <ChatForm room={props.match.params.roomname} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can then add to the rooms list with `setRooms`

```
setRooms([...rooms, {name: "New Room", src:"/new"}])
```

You'll need some sort of form to get the room name from the user.

Once you get the server set up, you'll have to create some sort of system to sync this with the database. I'd recommend storing data that's application-wide like this in redux, then you can build helper functions to handle queries and integrate them with redux.